# How can Anakin be father if Luke and Leia's birth happened after Anakin became Vader?

Tags: star-wars

In the *Star Wars*, Palpatine emphasized on this fact that Anakin was Luke's father, not Vader. My question is: How can Anakin be father if he was no more when Luke and Leia's birth happened?

Comment: oh no, somebody needs to re-watch Episode III and that video from health class...

Comment: @NKCampbell - "*When a Jedi and a Senator love each other very much...etc*"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anakin impregnated Padmé **before** he fell to the Dark Side and became Darth Vader. He is therefore the *biological* father, even though he had no hand in the twin's upbringing.

**Here we can see her giving him the happy news:**

Comment: Uh. Considering the outcome to the Galaxy... I'm quite hesitant to use the term "happy" in that specific context :)

Comment: @DVK - For me, the bigger question is what's going on with her bunhead hairdo. Does she actually think she looks good with [cinnamon swirls](http://www.deliciousmagazine.co.uk/recipes/cinnamon-and-raisin-swirls/) taped to the side of her head?

Comment: that's genetic. Her daughter has them. She has them too.

Answer (score 6):

### For all intents and purposes, Anakin Skywalker is dead

This is repeated multiple times throughout the movies.

In *Return of the Jedi*, Ben explains that Anakin no longer existed, only Vader.

> BEN
>   Your father was seduced by the dark side of the Force. He ceased to be 
>   Anakin Skywalker and became Darth Vader. When that happened, the good man who was your father was destroyed. So what I have told you was true... from a certain point of view.

Even Vader acknowledges that the name "Anakin" holds no meaning to him.

> LUKE: I've accepted the truth that you were once Anakin Skywalker, my father.
>
> VADER  (turning to face him)
>   That name no longer has any meaning for me.

**Anakin sired two children. He is the birth-father of Luke and Leia, even if he was "dead" before they were born.**

Comment: Hmm. Your answer has a big unnecessary header and inline quotes. Mine has an embedded youtube video... Let the battle commence!

Comment: "VADER (turning to face him) That name no longer has any meaning for me." Denial ain't just a river in Egypt.

Answer (score 5):

Because Anakin impregnated Padme.  Neither Anakin, nor Vader, played any role in the twins' upbringing.  Anakin/Vader's only contribution was biological, and that contribution occurred before Vader existed.

Comment: And let's not forget that Padme had no role in the twins' upbringing, either, yet I don't see anyone complaining that she wasn't their mother!